# Toggle-able "Soft" (temporary) line wrap of only the current line, in vim?

Tags: vim

99.9% of the time, I have line-wrapping turned off in vim.  But there are the rare occasions (usually, when looking at a generated debug or build log) where there is some egregiously-long line that I don't want to slowly scroll through.

Is there a vim command that will soft-wrap ONLY the current line, that can be just as quickly undone by another (or the same) vim command?   By "soft-wrap", I mean vim will only change the line's visual representation on the screen, not actually permanently break it up within the file buffer.

BONUS: can this line be temporarily colored differently, to make it more obvious where it begins and ends?   (I do not use line numbers, as they complicate copy-paste from within an xterm or tmux.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't soft wrap just one line, but you could reformat it with `gqq`, then hit `u` to undo when you're done.

You can highlight the current line with `:set cursorline`, though this would work better with `:set wrap`.